# html dynamically from require.js text! plugin

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

i'm trying to do a simple function where I get the string of a text! imported html file

currently its returning the function. how do i get it to return the text ?

this is within the initialize function of a backbone view.

```
  this.options.template =  req(['text!tpl/snippet/'+this.option.currentTemplate+'.html'], function(_template){ return _template; });
```

this.options.template is currently a function()

how do i get it to return the actual string ?

Comment: You need to execute the function? Is that what you mean?

Comment: not just execute the function. I need the string of the html. When i tried to execute the function all I receive is a function back. maybe its an async issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you need to execute the function (that will return the string), then this is the solution

```
var getTemplateText = this.options.template;
getTemplateText();
```